# Past perfect in a story

Tags: past-perfect

> Sitting up in bed, his cheeks still flushed with heat, Bill **had
> finished** the boat—but when George reached for it, Bill held it out
> of reach. “Now get me the paraffin.” “Where is it?”
> “It’s on the cellar shelf as you go downstairs,” Bill **said**.
> George **had gone**
> obediently to get these things. He could hear his mother playing the
> piano. <sub>Stephen King's It</sub>

Why is past perfect in order here?

The chronological order is this: Bill said to bring these things by pointing where they were (downstairs), then George went to bring them and as he was going to bring them he heard his mother playing the piano. This is the second chapter of the story.

The first chapter told about events that happened after Bill had pointed to these things and after George had brought them. The first chapter told about George running along beside a paper boat that had been made from the things that Bill had asked George to bring.

Comment: There is insufficient context to say why the usage of the present perfect is appropriate **if indeed it is**. Literally, it means that the time when George looked for some **things** occurred before the time that Bill told him where one of them (?) was. The piano playing seems irrelevant to the topic and uncertain as to time.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't provide enough context. The chronological order is actually this: Bill said to bring these things then George went to bring them and as he was going to bring them he heard his mother playing the piano.

Comment: "_The first chapter told about events that happened after Bill had pointed to these things and after George had brought them._" that's why _had gone_ is used - because it's looking back to an earlier time. I don't know why the author didn't use _Bill had said_, but you don't have to use the past perfect for every verb if the narrative reads better without.

Comment: @KateBunting Actually, it is because there were things at the beginning of the second chapter. Here: Sitting up in bed, his cheeks still flushed with heat, Bill **had finished** the boat—but when George reached for it, Bill held it out of reach. “Now get me the paraffin.”
“Where is it?”
“It’s on the cellar shelf as you go downstairs,” Bill **said**.

Comment: This is very, very simple: If what George did comes BEFORE what Bill said, the past perfect is fine. There is **always**something  preceding some past action, in fact or implied, when you use this tense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use the past perfect without an action described by past simple?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/254607/can-i-use-the-past-perfect-without-an-action-described-by-past-simple)

Comment: What is the source of the quoted text here, please? Author and title, and if possible a link also.

Comment: @Lambie no, it doesn't. All the uses that you listed in your reply are known to me, but the one I'm discussing here is new to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use past perfect twice in the same sentence in the context of a text written in past tense completely?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73483/can-i-use-past-perfect-twice-in-the-same-sentence-in-the-context-of-a-text-writt)

Comment: @Rusletov Your example to Kate illustrates exactly what I am saying. What I am saying applies to all uses of it. Its only use is as preceding something else in the past.

Comment: @Lambie yes, the past perfect points to some earlier event when we're already speaking about the past. As far as I know, we don't use the past perfect when we tell a story chronologically: "I came home, washed the dishes and then went to bed." but we use it like this "I came home and when/after I had washed the dishes I went to bed". The fact that the author uses the past perfect seems confusing because he seems to tell the story chronologically: Bill finishes the story, then George reaches for the boat, then George goes for the paraffin, then he hears his mother's playing.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is using (or perhaps setting) "story time" - the temporal focus, relative to which going to get the things is in the past.

If this is the beginning of the narrative, then it is establishing the story time, as a later time from which George is looking back to going to fetch the things. If it is not at the beginning, then the story time may already have been established.

The fact that Bill spoke in the simple past means that Bill's speaking is at story time, not the time when George went to fetch things, (though by its meaning, he has only just gone to fetch the things).

> ```
>  earlier ------------------- later ('now' in the story)
> ```
>
> George going to fetch ------------  Bill says... George can hear ...

Comment: Perhaps I didn't provide enough context. The chronological order is actually this: Bill said to bring these things then George went to bring them and as he was going to bring them he heard his mother playing the piano.

Comment: In that case, the tenses are anomalous, and the author is being careless or deliberately confusing. We often don't use the past perfect when we could, if the temporal relationships are clear. But to begin a narrative with a simple past and then follow it with a past perfect is unusual, and invites an explanation such as the one I gave.

Comment: I guess the author could have used the past perfect here because the previous chapter was about the future of the story, that is it told about events that happened  after George had already gotten the things.

Comment: Yes, that is what I would expect. But "Bill said" is anomalous.

Comment: I've added some more context to the original question. I think it may be clearer now why the author used "Bill said".

Comment: Right. Th author is moving "story time" on. First, it's when he's sitting up in bed, and _**had finished** the boat_ is previous. So _said_ is at story time. Then the _had gone_, because it clearly follows _said_, is moving "story time" to a later time, so now getting the things is in the past relative to the (new) story time.